# What's the constructor here?

Tags: java, constructor

The text of an exercise from a well known and basic Java programming textbook follows:

'Sometimes we would like a class that has just a single unique instance. Create a class Merlin that has one attribute, theWizard, which is static and of type Merlin. The class has only one constructor and two methods, as follows:
* Merlin —a private constructor. Only this class can invoke this construc-
tor; no other class or program can create an instance of Merlin
* summon —a static method that returns theWizard if it is not null; if theWizard is null, this method creates an instance of Merlin using the private constructor and assigns it to theWizard before returning it.
* consult—a non-static method that returns the string "Pull the sword 
from the stone" '

Were you able to understand what the author is asking in the point 'Merlin -a private constructor' ? I know what a constructor is as well as what a private method is. But here what's the answer ? I thought of something like

```
public class Merlin {
    private static Merlin theWizard;

    /*public Merlin()
    {
        ???
    }*/

    private Merlin()
    {
         this();
    }

    public static Merlin summon(Merlin theWizard) { 
        if (theWizard == null) {
            theWizard = new Merlin(); 
        return theWizard; 
    }

    public String consult() {
        return "Pull the sword from the stone"; 
    }
}
```

and of course JavaBeans says 'private Merlin()' is recursive. So what do I do ? The next exercise is related to the above one and could help you to understand what the answer is; here it is:

9. Create a program that tests the class Merlin described in the previous exercise.

   - Use the toString method to verify that a unique instance has been created.

Thank you very much for all that you will be able to tell me.

Comment: Well the constructor is only recursive because you've got `this()` in it...

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of the Singleton Pattern; in your case, just replace `this()` with `super()` to use the superclass's constructor (technically, if you don't place a super constructor call, the compiler will insert one for you; so you could just remove it).

Food for thought:

- why is the Merlin class `private`?
- why is the Merlin class `static`?
- where's the rest of your code?

Comment: The rest of my code is: public static Merlin summon(Merlin theWizard)
    {
        if (theWizard == null)
        {
            theWizard = new Merlin();
        } else
        {
                
        }
        
        return theWizard;
        
    }
    
    public String consult()
    {
        return "Pull the sword from the stone";
    }                                                                          It's static because for its nature the c

Comment: It's static because this constructor is used to build a class' object without the need of using a pre-existing object to call the constructor method itself. It's private because it has to be used onlly within the class (even though, I admit, it's not clear why to me ..)

Comment: I thank you very much for your answer. I'll try and complete exercise 9. Is the use of super(), which I haven't reached in the book yet, the only answer to this problem ? Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `this()`:

```
public class Merlin {

    private static Merlin theWizard;

    private Merlin() {}
    ...
}
```

`this` followed by parens is the syntax used to call a constructor of the same class, since you are not specifying any arguments inside the parens then you're referring to the no-argument instructor, which is the constructor this is being called from, so the constructor would call itself recursively until it runs out of stack space. The IDE is checking for this problem and trying to warn you about it.

Calling `super()` in the constructor is allowed (it calls the no-argument constructor in the superclass, which here is java.lang.Object) but not required, the compiler will insert a call to super if you don't.

By the way you can't have multiple overloads of a constructor or method with the same argument list. You can't have a public no-arg constructor and a private no-arg constructor.

The author is trying to describe a class that has control over how its instances are created, it makes its constructor private so that only the class itself is allowed to instantiate an object of that class.

Comment: Great Nathan ! You cleared my last doubts out of the way. Thank you so much to you too !